# Flash effect still over a pop-up div although i used wmode = transparent

Tags: jquery, flash, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using jquery Ui datepicker plugin and i have a dive containing swf element using swfobject script with option: (wmode:transparent) and (wmode:opaque)

I can view the datepicker but the problem is the effect of flash still over the datepicker.

when i click on the datepicker above the area that containing the transparent flash, the click event affect on flash not in the datepicker script.

What's the solution of this problem?

Comment: Did you try changing the z-indexs, while having the wmode on transparent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the z-indexs, while having the wmode on transparent :)